# Implementing lists with String and Int values paired

Tags: java, arraylist

How does a ArrayList react when one of the elements of a pair is entered as a null value?

My intent is to create a list for courses and the marks for those courses, but I'm wondering what happens if we don't enter a score for a course. Would that throw an exception or just leave a null value at that element position?

Comment: You could always just try it. Just saying...

Comment: The question you need to ask is how does "name of structure holding the string and int" handle one value being null... Or are you thinking of a Map and not a List

Comment: Dear @user1588867. Try something and ask a question if you couldn't achieve. People will help much better than your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists don't have "pairs" - I think you mean `Map`, not `List`. Lists have single values, maps have pairs.

Maps can have null values for a given key.

```
Map<String, Integer> coursePoints = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
coursePoints.put("ABC001", 5);
coursePoints.put("XYZ002". null); // OK
```

Comment: @Bhohemian Would I be able to declare the name of the Map based on another variable value? For example, if I was combining department and student references to form it, coming up with PhysicsBillyJones.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList`  supports null value but you can try Apache common collection library's `ListUtils#predicatedList`, Where returns a predicated list backed by the given list. Only objects that pass the test in the given predicate can be added to the list. It is important not to use the original list after invoking this method, as it is a backdoor for adding unvalidated objects(like `null`).

```
ListUtils.predicatedList(new ArrayList(), PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());
```

Here return list would be backed by `ArrayList` and it does not support `null` value.